# Magento 2: How to differentiate the app and web based orders?

Tags: magento2.2, sales-order, order-grid, php-7.2

How to identify whether the order is placed from an app or website?

I want to add one custom column in admin sales order grid. And the column displays the values for order source(app or website order).

How to get the order is placed from web or app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app must call an API to place an order in this API add a param "**requestPlatform**" and pass the request platform value in it such as "**android**" or "**ios**", based on this parameter you can differentiate that the order is placed from which platform.

for e.g

```
{
    "requestPlatform": "android"
}
```

Comment: For website orders?

Comment: for website you are not getting this parameter because it is for the API, and if the API call through an app you can check it otherwise the order is placed from web

Comment: I am also using this scenario for my store

Comment: @ASQ so mean you need to custom V1/carts/mine/payment-informationc or create new API? Can you please give more detail, bcoz from my opinion we can use the event 'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action' for success case and override Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Failure for fail case